# My max function is throwing an error even though its the same as my min function but flipped, can't find the error?

Tags: bash, unix, max, min

When I run ShellCheck on my script, it gives me these errors:

```
Line 27:
{
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this brace group.

Line 30:
for in `cat popconfile`
^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this for loop. Fix to allow more checks.
       ^-- SC1058: Expected 'do'.
       ^-- SC1072: Expected 'do'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#getalldata() {
#find . -name "ff_*" -exec  sed -n '4p' {} \;
#}

#Defining where the population configuration file is which contains all the data
popconfile=$HOME/testarea


#Function to find the average population of all of the files
averagePopulation()
{
total=0
list=$(cat popconfile)
for var in "${list[@]}"
do
    total=$((total + var))
done

average=$((total/$(${#list[*]} popconfile)))
echo "$average"
}

#Function to find the maximum population from all the files
maximumPopulation()
{
max=1

for in `cat popconfile`
do
if [[ $1 > "$max" ]]; then
max=$1
echo "$max"
fi
done
}

#Function to find the minimum population from all the files
minimumPopulation()
{
min=1000000
for in `cat popconfile`
do
if [[ $1 < "$min" ]]; then
max=$1
echo "$min"
fi
done
}

#Function to show all of the results in one place
function showAll()
{
echo "$min"
echo "$max"
echo "$average"
}
```

Although my `min` function is very similar, I get no error from it; if I switch my `min` and `max` function around, then the error is reported for the function that occurs first.

The error is just saying "*expected `do`*" - but I already have a `do` statement.  So where is the error?

Comment: You're missing the loop variable name in `for in cat...`, for doesn't set positional parameters, so you should provide your own name and use that instead of `$1`

Comment: Oh so basically I just need to change $1 to something like ma > "$max"?

Comment: You are missing your variable in the for loop, but most importantly, [never process a file with a for-loop](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Also, you might be interested in `awk`.

Comment: Both `max` and `min` have the same problem. `bash` never even tries to parse `minimumPopulation` because it stops on the syntax error in `maximumPopulation`.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense now, going to try it with a while read loop to see if i can get it working that way, really appreciate the help thanks both!

Comment: Is that a simple typo? `if [[ $1 < "$min" ]]; then
max=$1` should probably assign `min`, not `max`.

Comment: It is indeed, think i jumbled it up when i was trying to swap functions around etc to see why it wouldnt work

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the index in the `for` loop. The immediate fix would be

```
maximumPopulation()
{
max=1

for i in `cat popconfile`
do
if [[ $i > "$max" ]]; then
max=$i
echo "$max"
fi
done
}
```

However, you shouldn't use a `for` loop to iterate over the lines of a file; see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Instead, use a `while` loop.

```
maximumPopulation () {
  max=1
  while IFS= read -r i; do
    if (( i > max )); then
      max=$i
    fi
  done < popconfile
  printf '%d\n' "$max"
}
```