# Bash script to add directory size

Tags: bash, nested-loops

Can you please help me with below problem

Requirement : Have a list of directory locations on text file , I may need to create a script that will go through a text file and add the disk space.
I have a partally working script as below , but the script is  giving some syntax error in expression

```
#!/bin/bash 
sum=0  
m=1000 
for j in `cat filelist`  
do 
    if [ -f $j ]; 
    then 
            for i in `cat $j` 
    do  
x=`du -k $i |cut -f1`  
((sum+=$x))  
    done 
size=$(bc <<< "scale=3;$sum/$m")  
echo ${i##*/}, $size >> /tmp/size333.csv  
sum=  
    else  
        continue;    
    fi 
done
```

Note: here filelist has  values like

```
client_846.txt
client_847.txt
client_848.txt
client_849.txt
client_850.txt
client_851.txt
client_854.txt
client_855.txt
```

And in the `pwd` of script location we have all those text file
(client_854.txt, client_855.txt..etc ).

An example of client_854.txt will be like :

```
/home/abc/client_854
/home/bbb/sss/client_854
etc ..
```

Comment: Please add proper formatting in you posted source code. Indent the whole code with 4 spaces and all nested levels accordingly.

Comment: I hope the backslashes (`\ `) in front of each backquote (`\``) are present only in the code you posted here (as an initial unsuccessful attempt to format the code) and not in your real code. Anyway, make sure the code posted here matches the real code exactly (use copy-paste to be sure) or you'll get a lot of answers and comments to the wrong issue.

Comment: Hi axiac , Yes that was my attempt to format it initally  , the above code is exactily same as my orginal code, thanks again for that

Comment: ok, you have filelist, so what exactly you want to calculate, and where to put the results?

Comment: First read [My max function is throwing an error even though its the same as my min function but flipped, can't find the error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263677/my-max-function-is-throwing-an-error-even-though-its-the-same-as-my-min-function) answered minutes ago and look again at what you are doing. Then read [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and save the link to the site -- you will use that site over and over.

Comment: Hi hopetds , The filelist is a text file which contains a list of entries like  client_846.txt
client_847.txt
client_848.txt
client_849.txt
client_850.txt
client_851.txt
client_854.txt
client_855.txt  and each of those files has directory location  . Results may be in csv file , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A way to add size of files whose path is written into files listed into a file named filelist :

> cat filelist | xargs cat | xargs du -cs

Comment: the list i have is not files , but directories

Answer (score 0):

You are struggling on a number of fronts -- mostly because you are going about determining the size and reading the names from `filelist` in an incorrect manner.

When reading the contents of a file, a `while read -r line; do .... done <file` is the preferred method of reading a file. You also add a test for a non-POSIX line ending on the final line to insure the final line is processed, making the complete loop:

```
while read -r line || test -n "$line"
do
    ...
done < file
```

In your case you must (1) read a filename (located in `$PWD`) from `filelist`. Within the filename read is a list of absolute path filenames that you must (2) read and determine the size of each file on disk and then write the information to an output file that will contain the file and its size. Your use of `bc` is unclear, but if you are simply summing the sizes for each filename read from `filelist`, then simple integer math will do. (from your explanation I presume you want an output file that includes the individual size of each file read from each name in `filelist`.

To determine the size of the file, `stat -c %s filename` can be used to return the size (in bytes) of the file on disk. This eliminates your need for `cut` (which was unclear to begin with)

Putting those pieces together, you could write a short script to read each filename from each file in `filelist` and append `", size"` to the filename and write the data for all files involved to a new file `filelist_size`. (also included below in comments is how you would write the total sum for each file in `filelist` if that is what you are doing) e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" && {   ## validate filelist given as 1st argument
    printf "error: insufficient input.\nusage: %s <filelist>\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}
filelist="$1"
newfile="${filelist}_size"  ## name for file containing files/sizes
:> "$newfile"               ## truncate newfile

while read -r name || test -n "$name"   ## read each name in filelist
do  ## validate name exists in filesystem
    test -e "$name" || {    ## validate file exists
        printf "error: file does not exist '%s'.\n" "$name"
        continue 
    }
    ## sum=0  # reset sum if summing all sizes per-file
    while read -r filenm || test -n "$filenm"   ## read each filenm in name
    do  ## output absolute filenm and size to newfile
        test -e "$filenm" || {    ## validate file exists
            printf "error: file does not exist '%s'.\n" "$filenm"
            continue 
        }
        printf "%s, %d\n" "$filenm" "$(stat -c %s "$filenm")" >> "$newfile"
        ## sum = $((sum + $(stat -c %s "$filenm"))) # if summing
    done < "$name"
    ## printf "%s, %d\n" "$name" "$sum" >> "$newfile" # if summing
done < "$filelist"
```

(**note:** I don't have data files to test on, so you may need to adjust or tweak to your situation)

Also, don't strip the path from the absolute filenames in each file from `filelist` when outputting the file. The only time that would make sense is if you were only wanting a total for each file in `filelist` (which you could adjust the script above to produce easily, by removing the output to `newfile` and simply summing the result of `stat -c %s` for each file)

Look over the approach and let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using below script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line 
do
 if [ -s "$line" ];
       then
        x=`cat "$line" | xargs du -cs | cut -f 1 |tail -1`
        echo "$line","$x" >> result.csv
       else 
               continue;       
  fi
done < filelist
```